# solr partial word match

Tags: regex, solr, match, partial

Background:

- solr 4.10;
- linux/java - I guess they are irrelevant at this point;

I have this word: `ABCDEF`. I need to find all documents who's name (field: `NAME`) has a given number of letters in common with `ABCDEF`. Example: `ABCDEF` should match for a 4 letter match:

- itself (`ABCDEF`, `ABCD`, `BCDE`, etc);
- various permutations: `B..A.DE...`, `..F..A.DE...` - where dots are here other letters than the ones in `ABCDEF`.

I would try to use regex  (example: `^(.?)([ABCDEF] (.?)){4}$`), but this will also match `A..A..B..C` (`A` is there twice) and I don't need this one.

The field is type `string`. However, it will not be a problem to add another field to be tokenized and indexed differently.

Also, fuzzy search/match would not be an option - as I need those exact letters to appear in the matched field.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give any use case from your scenario so that I would know what exactly you want to do. Few months back I was also in a similar kind of situation while dealing with solr.

Comment: Well, it's simple: I have the name of a book and I need to search in solr if there is a book that starts with the same 2 letters (let's say) and it has 3 other letters in common with the original name. the position of the other 3 letters is not important, but it has not to overlap with the 2 letters in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Index each unique letter (or key) as a separate token - you can either split this up in your indexing code or use an update processor to split the field into characters. Be sure to use a field type that doesn't drop short tokens (such as stop words).

When you have a field with each letter / key by itself, use the `mm` parameter to (e)dismax to provide the number of terms that have to match, and provide the letters / keys to search for as separate terms.

```
Index: ABCDEF
Document: field: (A, B, C, D, E, F)

Query: BCDF
/select?q=B C D F&mm=4&defType=dismax

Query: BCDF, at least two must match
/select?q=B C D F&mm=2&defType=dismax
```